# What is realm in htdigest?

Tags: apache

htdigest needs the following parameters:

```
Usage: htdigest [-c] passwordfile realm username
```

What is the realm for?  What value should I use to setup htdigest?

Comment: This Q is not about programming at all, should be moved to serverfault or superuser

Comment: realm has to be something, you can't get away without specifying it in use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyway, realm denotes authentication domain for challenge-response. In the case of `digest` authentication realm value participates in the password hash, that why it is required when storing password files.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1 for details.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the realm is the same that the authname in your .htaccess as it will be displayed at prompt for login and password

i.e:

```
<Location /prived/>
AuthName "Prived zone"
AuthType Digest
AuthUserFile /var/www/authfile/priveduser
AuthGroupFile /var/www/authfile/privedgroup
AuthDigestDomain /prived/ /protect/
Require group valid-users
</Location>
```

htdigest -c /var/www/authfile/priveduser "Prived zone" titi

Answer (score 0):

When creating passwords with htdigest, 'realm' needs to match the 'AuthName' directive in your Apache config.

e.g., if your config for digest contains this:

`AuthName abc1234xyz`

then the htdigest command to create users will look like this:

`htdigest /path/to/digestfile abc1234xyz username`